# using tooltip for text overflows of dynamic data on div

Tags: html, css

I have a bound class inside a div whose data changes dynamically (every day). Some of this data which exceeds the length of the div is overflowing. I want to rectify these overflow errors by implementing a tooltip. I already have ellipsis in place which I implemented using css. I now want to implement a tooltip such that when I move the mouse and hover over the text which has been wrapped using ellipsis a tooltip should show up showing the complete text. I have done a lot of research on this and came up on a dead end since I havent found anything that explains how to get the tooltip to work on data whose length can change dynamically and to display the entire text in it. This is what I have in my code now:

```
    <div class="BoundClass">
                      <div class="EllipsisOverflow">                          
                           <%#Container.DataItem("cClassName")%>
                       </div>
                      </div>
```

```
   .BoundClass 
 {
     font-size: 14px;
     color: #fff;
     margin-left: -10px;
     position: relative;
     height: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 6px;
}

 .EllipsisOverflow
{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
 .EllipsisOverflow:hover:after
{
    content: attr(title);
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 220px;
    overflow:visible;
    text-overflow:clip;
}
```

This is the CSS for the bound class, and I also applied ellipsis to it

I am looking for a straightforward answer on this so anyone who could help out please do

Comment: The answer to this is dramatically affected by how you want it to look/interact. The easy answer is use a library like bootstrap. The not so easy answer involved CSS, extra elements, and some `:hover` selectors.

Comment: I dont want to use a third party library. So I think I have to take the other route. The issue where I am stuck is the div class and span class is the same bound class i.e., the text that is overflowing and has an ellipsis applied to and the text that needs to appear in the tooltip is the same. So I basically want to display the incomplete text which has been wrapped by the ellipsis in a tooltip and I am not finding an answer to this.

Comment: So basically, you are unsure how to make a tooltip without repeating the content in two element? Or do you not have an issue with that?

Comment: Why you don't set this title for the ellipsis div `title='<%#Container.DataItem("cClassName")%>'` ?

Comment: I understand what you want and must to say **It is impossible or very hard** There is not any css method to get the removed text by `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and you must to create some complicated codes to find how many text your div can show, then split that from original text and show in tooltip. I suggest you to extend the div on hover to an `height: auto` to show all of your text.

Answer (score 0):

A basic tooltip can be created like this

HTML:

```
<div class='parent'>
    Content
    <span class="tooltip">More Content</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
.parent:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

Basically, make the tooltip then hide it until you hover on the parent.

You can see a working example with your CSS and code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v79bh7b5/)

Comment: Here, my content and more content is inside the same div class. It is not a html statement. It is dynamic text inside a bound class coming from a database. So I need it to repeat it in the tooltip i.e., the entire text needs to be displayed in the tooltip

Comment: @user0594 - you have it in a div. Just repeat that div.

Comment: by repeat I mean I dont want the entire text to repeat. let me correct myself, i mean that the text which is not visible should be displayed along with the original visible text in the tooltip. And I did try out this code but it is just repeating the text in the container itself and not displaying a tooltip when I hover over it.